# IOS Serial Port Development

Tags: ios, command, port, at-command

Is there any method to access iphone serial port. I have search many documents but failed to send at command to tty.ipa or uart.debug port.

Comment: Short answer; no. Longer answer you need MFi certified hardware such as http://redpark.com/lightning-serial-cable-l2-db9v/. It would be easier to use a TCP connection to some sort of terminal server device

Comment: OK,thanks for your reply.

Comment: MFI certified need external accessory.It's not my resolution.I just want to get data from app inside.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The iPhone doesn't have a serial port that is user accessible. You need additional hardware such as I linked to. What are you trying to do?  What "AT" commands do you want to send?

Comment: OK,I see.Qualcomm has supplied this module for Apple.but System limited this function. I really don't understand。 I had remember It's ok in iphone 4.I just want send AT Command like "atd;","at+cgatt=".

Comment: There is no way to access the iPhone as a "modem".